# Sync / Import MySQL to Outlook Contacts

Tags: mysql, outlook, contacts

I want to connect my MySQL-Database with some contact data with Outlook 2010. Is there a possibility without buying an expensive programm? Maybe using ODBC?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045302/import-sync-contacts-from-sql-server-to-outlook